# How setup C++ SDK in IntelliJ IDEA on linux?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, sdk, intellij-idea

I need to know how to configure the path to C++ SDK for IntelliJ IDEA 10.04.
I installed C/C++ plugin, however I don't know what is the proper path to C++ SDK.

I am using ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: This question is not answered. Linking us to a site that writes "Specify C++ sdk if needed" is not helpful. I believe the OP is asking for a description of what the intellij plugin is looking for when one specifies a c++ SDK. What path root defines a C++ sdk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after installing the c++ plugin you should see the C/C++ project option when you create a new module - i think you're seeing the point where it's asking you for the cpp sdk location.

run

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

Then restart intellij - it should autodetect that it's installed and offer you the option in the drop down instead of asking you to browse to the SDK directory

Answer (score 10):

after running

```
sudo aptitude install build-essential
```

then restart idea and go to terminal and run

```
which gcc
```

now copy the output into ideas settings -> IDE settings -> c/c++
and paste what you copied into the path to gcc.

do the same process for the gdb

after doing that then idea will add the sdk to the drop down menu in the create project menu

Comment: Running idea 14.0.2 I found the menu under file > settings > other settings > c/c++